# Should type information be provided for the 'self' argument in cython extension types?

Tags: cython

I've been experimenting with wrapping C++ with cython. I'm trying to understand the implications of typing `self` in extension type methods.

In the [docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html) `self` is not explicitly typed but it seems like there could potentially be speedups associated with typing `self`.

However, in my limited experimentation, explicitly typing `self` does not seem to yield performance increases. Is there special magic going on under the covers to handle `self`, or is this purely a style thing?

**EDIT** for clarity:

By typing `self`, I mean providing type information for the `self` argument of a method. i.e.:

```
cdef class foo:
    cpdef bar(self):
        # do stuff with self
```

vs

```
cdef class foo:
    cpdef bar(foo self):
        # do stuff with self
```

Comment: I agree that typing 'self' or any other name for the own class object should be purely matter of convention...

Comment: Not any difference I think, since in both case in the generated c codes `self` is converted to `struct xxxxxx_foo *__pyx_v_self` in the c parts, and `PyObject *__pyx_v_self` in the Python wrapper.(You can easily check that in jupyter notebook by `%%cython -a ` cell magic)

Comment: @oz1 looks like you are correct for the general case. The reason I started down this path was the apparent need to type self in an `__eq__` method. I did your notebook trick and there are indeed differences for `__eq__` and perhaps other magic functions.

Comment: `(struct __pyx_obj_46_cython_magic_a97a4609d42faba2d2376a5b3cd09730_foo *)__pyx_v_self` for one and `(PyObject *)__pyx_v_self` for the other

Comment: As far as I know, special methods must be `def` functions, thus the `self` shoud always be `(PyObject *)__pyx_v_self` in the python wrapper.  Indeed the wrapped function is different in the signature, one is (PyObject *) for not typed `self`, the other is `struct *` which possibly has fewer pointer  indirections. I think there is not much performance difference in the python part.

Comment: Moreover the typed `self` one has more thick yellow colors than the other, which indicates more Python API invoked. If not sure, just profile it :)

Comment: @oz1 indeed it does. You should write all this up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already worked out, normally `self` is "translated" to the right type in the resulting c-code.

The only exceptions I'm aware of are the [rich comparison operators](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/special_methods.html#rich-comparison-operators), i.e. `__eq__`, `__lt__`,`__le__` and so one.

The other special methods/operators like `+=` or `+` work exactly in the same way as all other "normal" methods: `self` is automatically of the right type.

However, the behavior of the rich comparison operators will be changed soon, as it seems to be only a glitch in the newly introduced feature: [corresponding issue](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1935).

---

Now, that we have established, what the cython does do, the interesting question is why cython does it this way.

For somebody comming from static typed languages it is pretty obvious, that `self` can be only of the class-type (exact this class or derived from this class) for which this function is defined, so I would expect `self` to be of this class-type. So it would be a surprise if cython would behave differently.

Yet it is probably not so clear in the age of duck-typing and mokey-patching in which classes can be changed dynamically. Let's take a look at the following example:

```
 []class A:
    def __init__(self, val):
         self.val=val
    def __str__(self):
       return "value=%s"%self.val

 []class B:
     def __init__(self, val):
        self.val="<"+val+">"

 [] a,b=A(1.0),B("div")
 [] print a
 value=3
 [] print b
 <__main__.B instance at 0x0000000003D24E08>
```

So if we don't like how print handles the class `B`. It is possible to monkey-patch the class `B`  via:

```
 []B.__str__=lambda self: "value=%s"%self.val
 []print b
 value=<div>
```

So if we like the way the class `A` handles the `__str__` method, we could try to "reuse" it:

```
 []B.__str__=lambda self: A.__str__(self)
 []print b
 TypeError: unbound method __str__() must be called 
            with A instance as first argument 
            (got B instance instead)
```

So it is not possible: python checks for calls to `A.__str__(self)` that `self`  is really of type `A`.

Thus, cython is right in using the right type for `self` directly  and not a python object.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

There is no need to *verbosely* type `self` in a class method. It's not much faster than a plain `self`.

**Long answer:**

Although there are indeed some differences in the generated c codes(One can easily check it in jupyter notebook with magic cell `%%cython -a`). For example:

```
%%cython -a

# Case 1
cdef class foo1:
    def bar(self, foo1 other):
        pass
    def __eq__(self, foo1 other):
        pass

# Case 2
cdef class foo2:
    def bar(self, foo2 other):
        pass
    def __eq__(foo2 self, foo2 other):
        pass
```

1. In the Python wrapper, `self` is always converted to `PyObject *`.
2. For normal method(`bar`), the wrapped C function signatures are identical, `self` are both converted to `struct xxx_foo *`.
3. For magic method(`__eq__`), in the wrapped C function, plain `self` is converted to `PyObject *`, but the typed `foo2 self` is converted to `struct xxx_foo2 *`. In the latter case, the python wrapper cast `PyObject *` to `struct xxx_foo2 *` and call the wrapped C function. Case 2 may have fewer pointer indirections, but there should be not much difference in performance in both case. Besides, case 2 will do more checks in the python wrapper. In practice, the profile can say everything.